# Exception with mail content when retrieving mail from imap server using javamail

Tags: jakarta-mail, imap

I am retrieving mail from an imap server and when i am executing `message.getContent();` where message is `javax.mail.Message`
i am getting the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot convert DataSource with content type "TEXT/XML; charset=utf-8; name=FILENAME.XML" to object in XmlDataContentHandler
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.XmlDataContentHandler.getContent(XmlDataContentHandler.java:99)
    at javax.activation.DataSourceDataContentHandler.getContent(DataHandler.java:790)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.getContent(DataHandler.java:537)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getContent(MimeMessage.java:1419)
```

Comment: Tell me more about your environment.  Are you running in an app server?  What jar files are on your classpath?  I think this is due to a conflict between JavaMail and JAX-WS; the wrong DataContentHandler is being used.

Comment: Yes, there is a java EE application deployed on glassfish. Not sure if it helps but it doesn't happen all the time.

Comment: What version of GlassFish?  Can you expand on "doesn't happen all the time"?  What changes between when it happens and when it doesn't happen?  Redeploy app?  Restart server?  I don't suppose you have a simple test program that reproduces the problem, at least sometimes?

Comment: I am using GlassFish Server 3.1.2 Open Source Edition. I mean that the problem doesn't happen with all mails. The sender is always the same and all emails have always one xml file attachment. For those without a problem mails also contain other attachments eg. FILE.PDF etc. which i think makes the content type mime/multipart.

Comment: It sounds like the problem should be reproducible for messages of a certain type.  If you can construct a small program that reproduces the problem, that would help us debug it.  You  might also want to try GlassFish 4.0 to see if the problem has already been fixed there.

Comment: Unfortunately the system is in production and there is no plan to upgrade glassfish soon. After a communication with the sender we found out that for mails with the exception they are using "single-part MIME" format and maybe java mail fails to get content. A dirty fix that worked for us is to get the file contents from message.getInputStream()

Comment: I was able to reproduce your problem.  It still fails in GlassFish 4.0.  The workaround you're using of using getInputStream instead of getContent is probably the most reliable.

Comment: Thank you for all of your answers and help.